# Ajax call returns undefined data (when trying to receive mysql rows)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I have been trying to send the data I receive from mysql using Nodejs and try to receive it with Ajax. However, for some reason what I receive is always undefined.

The problem is either the way I am sending it or the way I receive it. Here is my question in more detail and code:

I have a form/ button.

```
<form id = "loadform" action= "/loaded" method ="POST">
        <input placeholder = "Zip Code(Optional)" name = 'zipcode'>
        <button id= "datasubmit">Load Data</button>
</form>
```

When clicked I expect this query to be executed. And it receives the correct data and prints out to the console correctly.

```
app.post('/loaded', function(req,res){

    connection.query("SELECT * FROM fmpDBTable", function(error,rows,fields){
        if(error){
           console.log('Error in the query')
         }
        else{
          console.log('successful query')
          console.log(rows[0].Latitude)
          console.log(rows.length)
          res.status(204).json(rows);
       }
    })
})
```

and I expect to have the following Ajax call executed when I click the submit button

```
$('#datasubmit').click(function(e){
    //alert("jhhfdsfs")
    $.ajax({
        url: 'loaded/',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: (data) =>{
            alert("checkpoint1")
            console.log(data)
        }
    })  
})
```

Great so far. However, the data that I am seeing is undefined (when I check it inspector console). Alert works btw

Where am I going wrong? I have checked bunch of similar threads and still not sure where I am going wrong

Comment: It's better to listen for the form's _submit_ event, and don't forget to call `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @Phil I still get undefined data :/

Comment: The code in your question has not changed so I wouldn't expect anything different either

Comment: You're returning status 204 (No-Content) then adding a content. Try changing this status to 200.

Comment: https://http.cat/204

Comment: And btw, it seems like this should be a "GET" instead of POST.

Comment: I'll make this a response so you can accept it.

Comment: @RenanSouza will do!

Comment: Well, @Phil marked this as duplicated, but I don't think this is true. Can't post answer then.

Comment: @RenanSouza the request method (GET / POST / etc) is irrelevant

Comment: @Phil yes for retuning data, not for context. It's really relevant that you categorize then in the correct way. If you are getting data, this is a get, if you're posting, it's a post.

Comment: I've added another duplicate referencing the 204 response status problem

Comment: Nice job then. *flies away*